# Unable to access document property from webpage using chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So there is a [new API](https://webmonetization.org/), proposed as a W3C standard, but to use it you need to have [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/coil/locbifcbeldmnphbgkdigjmkbfkhbnca) for now.

The extension adds an additional `document` key named `monetization`, which you can access with `document.monetization`. And also, the website must have a `payment pointer` to be able to access it.

I'm trying to access it with an extension I am developing, but I get an undefined error. Here's my `manifest.json`

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test Ext",
  "description": "Test Description",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_pop": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "A popup will come here."
  },
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["app.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

and in my `app.js`, I made a simple script to check if `document.monetization` is loaded.

```js
const tid = setInterval( function () {
    if (document.monetization === undefined) return;
    console.log('Accessible', document.monetization);
    clearInterval( tid );       
}, 100 );
```

But it's not working. How do you manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we can see in the source code of that extension `document.monetization` is an [expando](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Expando) property on a standard DOM `document` interface, this property is not a part of DOM, it's essentially a JavaScript object so it's not accessible directly from a content script which runs in an isolated world - all JavaScript objects/variables/expandos are isolated so the page scripts can't see the JS objects of content scripts and vice versa.

In Chrome to access such an expando property you need to [run the code in page context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879) and then use standard DOM messaging via CustomEvent to coordinate the code in page context and the content script as shown in a [sibling answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198) in the same topic.

In Firefox you can use [wrappedJSObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Sharing_objects_with_page_scripts) e.g. `document.wrappedJSObject.monetization`

Comment: Hello thank you for this. I'll review the post and get back to you on this.

Comment: That definitely did it! Awesome! I'll post my code on how did I make it work also. Thanks again.